# Boot problems in Ubuntu 22.10 - startx doesn't work

Tags: boot, xorg, 22.10

I am using a desktop with dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 22.10. I started to experience a really strange behavior from the Ubuntu two days ago, when I added a new HDD and installed some updates at about the same time. When I start my Ubuntu, I get the following error messages that don't seem to do anything with each other and after I get redirected to tty.

```
x86/CPU: SGX disabled by BIOS
usbhid 1-4:1.1: couldn'4 find an input interrupt endpoint
Dev loop56: unable to read RDB block 8
overlayfs: missing 'lowerdir'
Failed to start Service for snap application slurm.slurmdbd
```

These error messages just flash up and after I get redirected to tty, which seems to work normally. Except when I try to run *startx*, I get an "xinit: connection to Y server lost" error.
I am enclosing the whole log to startx, which I find also very strange, because it's biggest problem seems to be that it can't find my mouse (?)

```
[   457.705] 
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   457.723] Current Operating System: Linux no-2 5.19.0-26-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Nov 23 20:44:15 UTC 2022 x86_64
[   457.723] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-26-generic root=UUID=ae9ed941-f1d8-4d37-b9dd-41b6db410bc5 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[   457.736] xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.2 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   457.742] Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
[   457.754]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   457.754] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   457.779] (==) Log file: "/home/deltagene/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Dec 14 12:48:07 2022
[   457.779] (II) Loader magic: 0x563261cfe020
[   457.779] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   457.779]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   457.779]    X.Org Video Driver: 25.2
[   457.779]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.4
[   457.779]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   457.786] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[   457.789] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   457.789] (II) Platform probe for /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0
[   457.791] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 13 paused 0
[   457.797] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:3e92:1849:3e92 rev 0, Mem @ 0xde000000/16777216, 0xc0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x0000f000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   457.798] List of video drivers:
[   457.798]    amdgpu
[   457.798]    ati
[   457.798]    intel
[   457.798]    nouveau
[   457.798]    qxl
[   457.798]    radeon
[   457.798]    vmware
[   457.798]    modesetting
[   457.798]    fbdev
[   457.798]    vesa
[   457.798] (II) LoadModule: "amdgpu"
[   457.799] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/amdgpu_drv.so
[   457.801] (II) Module amdgpu: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.801]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 22.0.0
[   457.801]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.801]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.801] (II) LoadModule: "ati"
[   457.801] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/ati_drv.so
[   457.802] (II) Module ati: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.802]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 19.1.0
[   457.802]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.802]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.802] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
[   457.802] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/intel_drv.so
[   457.805] (II) Module intel: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.805]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.99.917
[   457.805]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.805]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.806] (II) LoadModule: "nouveau"
[   457.806] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nouveau_drv.so
[   457.807] (II) Module nouveau: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.807]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 1.0.17
[   457.807]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.807]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.807] (II) LoadModule: "qxl"
[   457.807] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/qxl_drv.so
[   457.808] (II) Module qxl: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.808]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.1.5
[   457.808]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.808]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.808] (II) LoadModule: "radeon"
[   457.809] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so
[   457.811] (II) Module radeon: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.811]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 19.1.0
[   457.811]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.811]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.811] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
[   457.811] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
[   457.878] (II) Module vmware: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.878]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 13.3.0
[   457.878]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.878]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.878] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[   457.879] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[   457.879] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.879]    compiled for 1.21.1.4, module version = 1.21.1
[   457.879]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.879]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.879] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   457.879] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   457.879] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.879]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 0.5.0
[   457.880]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.880]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.880] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   457.880] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   457.880] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   457.880]    compiled for 1.21.1.3, module version = 2.5.0
[   457.880]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   457.880]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 25.2
[   457.880] xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
[   457.880] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Integrated Graphics Chipsets:
    i810, i810-dc100, i810e, i815, i830M, 845G, 854, 852GM/855GM, 865G,
    915G, E7221 (i915), 915GM, 945G, 945GM, 945GME, Pineview GM,
    Pineview G, 965G, G35, 965Q, 946GZ, 965GM, 965GME/GLE, G33, Q35, Q33,
    GM45, 4 Series, G45/G43, Q45/Q43, G41, B43
[   457.881] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) HD Graphics
[   457.881] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics
[   457.881] (II) intel: Driver for Intel(R) Iris(TM) Pro Graphics
[   457.881] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[   457.881] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   457.881] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   457.882] (++) Using config file: "/home/deltagene/xorg.conf.new"
[   457.882] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   457.883] (==) ServerLayout "X.org Configured"
[   457.883] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   457.883] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   457.884] (**) |   |-->Device "Card0"
[   457.884] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[   457.884] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[   457.884] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   457.884] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   457.884] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   457.884] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   457.884] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   457.884]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   457.884] (**) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    built-ins
[   457.884] (**) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   457.884] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[   457.884] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[   457.884] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[   457.885] (II) intel(0): Using Kernel Mode Setting driver: i915, version 1.6.0 20201103
[   457.885] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2:2.99.917+git20210115-1 (Timo Aaltonen <tjaalton@debian.org>)
[   457.885] (II) intel(0): SNA compiled for use with valgrind
[   457.888] 
[   457.888] 
Xorg is not able to detect your mouse.
Edit the file and correct the Device.
[   457.888] 
Your xorg.conf file is /home/deltagene/xorg.conf.new

[   457.888] To test the server, run 'X -config /home/deltagene/xorg.conf.new'

[   457.944] (EE) Server terminated with error (2). Closing log file.
```

What I tried so far:

- cleaning up some space at the boot drive
- updating and upgrading everything
- fixing broken packages
- fixing the system using a boot USB and boot-repair

Nothing seems to solve the problems

Thanks for the help in advance

EDIT:

I attempted to fix the issue with the mouse following this post:
https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-431272-start-0.html

Xorg still gives the xinit:connection to Y server lost" error, but the log seems even stranger (I am trimming the log to fit into 30000 characters)

```
[    86.710] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event2)
[    86.710] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    86.710] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[    86.710] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[    86.714] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[    86.715]    compiled for 1.20.14, module version = 1.2.1
[    86.715]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[    86.715]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[    86.715] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    86.715] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    86.715] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[    86.721] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.721] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    86.722] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[    86.754] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event2"
[    86.754] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[    86.754] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    86.754] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "hu"
[    86.805] (II) event2  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.805] (II) event2  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    86.808] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event7)
[    86.808] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    86.808] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    86.808] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[    86.808] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[    86.811] (II) event7  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.811] (II) event7  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    86.811] (II) event7  - Video Bus: device removed
[    86.830] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input7/event7"
[    86.830] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[    86.830] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    86.830] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "hu"
[    86.834] (II) event7  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.834] (II) event7  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[    86.836] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[    86.836] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    86.836] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    86.836] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[    86.836] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[    86.839] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.839] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    86.839] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[    86.862] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1/event1"
[    86.862] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[    86.862] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    86.862] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "hu"
[    86.865] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.865] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[    86.867] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event0)
[    86.868] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    86.868] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    86.868] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[    86.868] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[    86.870] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.870] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    86.871] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
[    86.886] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0/event0"
[    86.886] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 9)
[    86.886] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    86.886] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "hu"
[    86.889] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.889] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[    86.894] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD (/dev/input/event4)
[    86.894] (**) SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    86.894] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD'
[    86.894] (**) SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD: always reports core events
[    86.894] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[    86.899] (II) event4  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.899] (II) event4  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD: device is a keyboard
[    86.900] (II) event4  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD: device removed
[    86.926] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.0/0003:258A:0001.0002/input/input4/event4"
[    86.926] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[    86.926] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    86.926] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "hu"
[    86.931] (II) event4  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.931] (II) event4  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD: device is a keyboard
[    86.935] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control (/dev/input/event5)
[    86.935] (**) SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    86.935] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control'
[    86.935] (**) SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control: always reports core events
[    86.935] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event5"
[    86.939] (II) event5  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.940] (II) event5  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control: device is a keyboard
[    86.940] (II) event5  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control: device removed
[    86.966] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.1/0003:258A:0001.0003/input/input5/event5"
[    86.966] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[    86.966] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    86.966] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "hu"
[    86.971] (II) event5  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.971] (II) event5  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control: device is a keyboard
[    86.975] (II) config/udev: Adding input device SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control (/dev/input/event6)
[    86.975] (**) SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[    86.975] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control'
[    86.975] (**) SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control: always reports core events
[    86.975] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[    86.979] (II) event6  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    86.979] (II) event6  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
[    86.980] (II) event6  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control: device removed
[    87.006] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-11/1-11:1.1/0003:258A:0001.0003/input/input6/event6"
[    87.006] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control" (type: KEYBOARD, id 12)
[    87.006] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[    87.006] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "hu"
[    87.011] (II) event6  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[    87.011] (II) event6  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control: device is a keyboard
[    87.015] (II) config/udev: Adding input device KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse (/dev/input/event3)
[    87.015] (**) KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[    87.015] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse'
[    87.015] (**) KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: always reports core events
[    87.015] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[    87.078] (II) event3  - KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    87.078] (II) event3  - KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: device is a pointer
[    87.079] (II) event3  - KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: device removed
[    87.122] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/0003:0458:0186.0001/input/input3/event3"
[    87.122] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 13)
[    87.123] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[    87.123] (**) KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[    87.123] (**) KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    87.123] (**) KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    87.186] (II) event3  - KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[    87.186] (II) event3  - KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: device is a pointer
[    87.189] (II) config/udev: Adding input device KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[    87.189] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.189] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.191] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line (/dev/input/event10)
[    87.191] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.191] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.192] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Line Out (/dev/input/event11)
[    87.192] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.192] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.193] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone (/dev/input/event12)
[    87.194] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.194] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.195] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event13)
[    87.195] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.195] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.196] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event14)
[    87.196] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.196] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.198] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 (/dev/input/event15)
[    87.198] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.198] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.199] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 (/dev/input/event16)
[    87.199] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.199] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.201] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Front Mic (/dev/input/event8)
[    87.201] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.201] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    87.202] (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic (/dev/input/event9)
[    87.202] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[    87.202] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    88.526] (--) intel(0): HDMI max TMDS frequency 300000KHz
[    89.007] (II) event2  - Power Button: device removed
[    89.054] (II) event7  - Video Bus: device removed
[    89.074] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[    89.098] (II) event0  - Sleep Button: device removed
[    89.114] (II) event4  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD: device removed
[    89.138] (II) event5  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD System Control: device removed
[    89.154] (II) event6  - SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD Consumer Control: device removed
[    89.170] (II) event3  - KYE SYSTEMS CORP. Wired Mouse: device removed
[    89.205] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    89.205] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    89.205] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    89.206] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    89.206] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    89.206] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    89.206] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    89.207] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[    89.290] (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "when I added a new HDD"? Did you swap out the system drive, or just add an additional drive?

Comment: I just added an additional drive